# Notepad ++ FIND/REPLACE Regex Wildcard

Tags: notepad++, regex

I have a text file with a list of filenames like so.

**ABC-FS01-E-20110515045349.txt**

I am trying to find a way in Notepad ++ to parse it like the following.

**ABC-FS01-E-2011-05-15**

I've tried using Regex, but my syntax is incorrect and I keep getting garbage.

Any thoughts?  Thanks!

Comment: My thought: you get what you give... /joke

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RegExp Search:

```
(ABC-FS[0-9]{2}-E-[0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2}).*
```

Replace:

```
\1-\2-\3
```

I know what you're thinking: "What kind of sorcery is that?" :)